# SQL Constraints on same entered table

Tags: mysql, key

Im using workbench but I came to a wall. I have searched around and every example that I have found so far has been simple examples. Here is my problem. Is it possible to have one table that has 2 foreign keys but one of them checks itself? Ill change the names to make it more interesting. Here is the example
table 1 : system groups (2 columns, id and name) table contains: 1 sega, 2 snes

table 2: sega games (2 columns, id and name) table contains: 1 sonic, 2 streets of rage

table 3: snes games (2 columns, id and name) table contains: 1 mario world, 2 tetris attack

table 4: players (4 columns, name, lname, system, game)
example:
carlos munoz snes sonic

if I hit apply I wanted to fail because the constrains should check snes in the table 1 and based on that check sonic on table 2. The foreign key worked for system check but how do I add a check for the game based on the system answer ?
I am using mysql for now.
I must say that I am new to this so if it is something simple feel free to flame me. I know how to do this using a simple table(everything together not divided ) but now Im trying to have it organized.
Thanks.